# Moodle - Plugin to create forms

Tags: php, forms, moodle, moodle-api

I'm new to Moodle and there is a new project in my office that I want to do.

What I want to do is to create a plugin that helps you create forms. For example, if I want to create a simple register form within Moodle or a simple questions form, the plugin must be able to manage the different type of labels (mail, text, drop-down, select, check, etc.), store the form in a database (form1, form2) and create the table for the respective form.

How should I approach this? Is this possible in Moodle? Or do I just code it in another language and make a generator? Maybe a local plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is something similar in Moosh although I haven't tried it myself.

http://moosh-online.com/commands/

```
moosh generate-form form_name
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. There is at least one existing form builder plugin for Moodle that could serve you as a good inspiration source:

- repo: https://github.com/WisdmLabs/moodle-local_edwiserform
- docs: https://edwiser.org/forms/edwiser-forms-documentation